# How to solve "package com.sun.javafx.css is declared in module jfxrt, but module Library does not read it""

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx-11

I created a new Java project (Library) in IntelliJ IDEA and copied the files from DockFX (https://github.com/RobertBColton/DockFX) to try and run the demo but I get the error "package com.sun.javafx.css is declared in module jfxrt, but module Library does not read it". The classes are all in a package called dockfx. I configured the project to run on JDK 11 in Project Structure. I've added jfxrt.jar from JRE 7 to the Classpath. Can you please tell me what I'm missing? Thanks.

When I try to run, I get

```
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'Library'
```

Information:javac 11.0.3 was used to compile java sources
Information:Module "Library" was fully rebuilt due to project configuration/dependencies changes
Information:27/06/2019 15:52 - Build completed with 100 errors and 0 warnings in 17 s 293 ms
src\dockfx\DockPane.java
Error:(27, 22) java: package com.sun.javafx.css is not visible
(package com.sun.javafx.css is declared in module jfxrt, but module Library does not read it)
Error:(29, 14) java: package javafx.animation is not visible
(package javafx.animation is declared in module jfxrt, but module Library does not read it)

Comment: Adding the `jfxrt.jar` from JRE 7 (!!) to run with JDK 11 looks like a terrible idea, doesn't it? JavaFX 11 is not part of the JDK anymore, but you can find it as standalone SDK or as artifact in Maven Central. Please have a look at https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/. You could try to run DockFX with JDK 1.8. Or you could check this [issue](https://github.com/RobertBColton/DockFX/issues/38) that points to a working fork of DockFX working with Java 11.

Comment: @JoséPereda thanks for your suggestions and especially the link. It seems to be referring to similar problems I've been having. I will let you know how I get on.